# How to actual plot properly via Plotly

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, exe, plotly-python

I have a problem with the plotly package. To be precise, I'm using auto-py-to-exe in order to have a file .exe which, if the users asks for it, plots a table using the plotly package. My code goes like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy

df= pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Program\Data_Studio_Def.xls')
visualize_table= input('visualize table of patologies? (yes/no)')
if visualize_table== yes
   fig = go.Figure(...)
   fig.show()
```

Now, when I run the .exe made by auto-py-to-exe on the CMD (OS: Windows 10), I get some errors regarding modules like

> Module plotly.validators.table not found

Once I add all such modules via hidden-import, I get the error:

> FileNotFoundError No such file or directory : C\Users\user\output...

so it is searching for the plot in a folder rather than actually print it and I don't know how resolve this. Should I provide further informations?

P.S. I found out that the main problem is caused by the plotly package itself: I tried to build the exe via cx_Freeze rather than pyinstaller and the result was:

> Module plotly.validators.table has no Attribute CellsValidators

Doing some searching I found out I'm not the only one with the same problem, the "HasNoAttribute", but uninstalling the package to then reinstall it again didn't do anything unfortunately.